# So how to change request cookies when spider use rules crawl pages?

Tags: cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

In start_request method, you can modify the start_urls requests cookie.
But I defined some rules, and spider crawl pages use these rules. So how to change request cookies when spider use rules crawl pages?

```
class MoiveSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "movieTop250"
allowed_domains = ["movie.douban.com"]
start_urls = ["https://movie.douban.com/top250"]
is_forbiden = False
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'https://movie.douban.com/top250\?start=\d+.*'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'https://movie.douban.com/subject/\d+')),
         callback="parse_item"),
]

def request(self, url):
    request = scrapy.Request(url=url,
                             meta={'dont_merge_cookies': self.is_forbiden},)
    request.cookies["cookie"] = "bid=%s" % "".join(
        random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 11))
    return request

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield self.request(url)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = parse_movie_item(self, response)
    return item
```